# How to add legend for color saturation distribution into power bi Filled Map chart

Tags: charts, legend, powerbi, dashboard

i have a power bi report "Filled Map" chart, where Location = "Cedent Country", and Color Saturation = "Percentage Brokerage Over Premium".

```
Percentage Brokerage Over Premium = Percentage Brokerage Over Premium = IFERROR(Round(SUM('Production ReportV20-V1 Power B'[Total Brokerage])/SUM('Production ReportV20-V1 Power B'[Cedent Premium]),2),0)
```

In Format --> Data Colors i configured color saturation as below:

- Minimum: Red
- Center: Orange
- Maximum: Green

I need to show in the chart Legend to display color distribution (Minimum: red, Center: Orange, Maximum: Green), but i couldn't find the option any where.

I created another field `Description = IF([Percentage Brokerage Over Premium]<0.1,"Low",IF([Percentage Brokerage Over Premium]>0.25,"High","Medium"))` and tried to drag it into Legend field section however nothing happened.

appreciate your assistance.

Best regards,

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Legend` field only accepts a `column`, not `measures` as input. Therefore nothing will happen if you drag the measure to the field.

The reason why it only accepts a column is because it doesn't serve the purpose as what you mean for legend (i.e. concise explanation of the symbols used in a chart, diagram, drawing, map, table, etc.) [[1]](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/legend.html) 
 Rather, it's for further slicing/breakdown of the data that you are interested in (e.g. Premium type/LOB, etc).

So my suggestion is that you can simply add a text box to type the legend (i.e. `High: red, Medium: orange, Low: green`); or better you can add an image with the diverging color and description to the report, like below.

[image: legend]

Comment: but how can i add the above image to the chart, is that doable?

Comment: @GeorgesSabbagh You can add the image to the report page directly by `Insert -> Image`. If you really want to put it on the chart then you can apply  some cosmetic changes, e.g. `Format -> Arrange -> Bring to front` to keep it above the chart.

Comment: this would be the perfect solution, however i tried to format image Format: bring forward, the image is above the chart, however whenever i select the chart it will disappear, i need it to be above the chart even if i select the chart it self.

Comment: it worked perfectly now .. thank you for your assistance. @Foxan Ng

Comment: @GeorgesSabbagh Glad to help!

Comment: This is ridicilous for a "BI Tool". There should be a dynamic legend included in the visual..

Answer (score 0):

Select chart and Visualizations -> select format tab

1) Select Data Colors 
[image]

2) select conditional formatting on Default color near right side icon 
[image]
[image]

3) Select Minimum and Maximum color
[image]